# multiple packages in context:component-scan, spring config

Tags: java, spring, component-scan

How can I add multiple packages in spring-servlet.xml file in `context:component-scan` element?

I have tried

```
<context:component-scan base-package="z.y.z.service" base-package="x.y.z.controller" />
```

and

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.service, x.y.z.controller" />
```

and

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.controller" />
```

but got error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [x.y.z.dao.daoservice.LoginDAO] found for dependency:
```

Answer (score 294, accepted):

The following approach is correct:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.service, x.y.z.controller" />
```

Note that the error complains about `x.y.z.dao.daoservice.LoginDAO`, which is not in the packages mentioned above, perhaps you forgot to add it:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.service, x.y.z.controller, x.y.z.dao" />
```

Comment: This answer implies that there is NOT recursion for the members of base-package BUT there IS:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774295/spring-xml-file-configuration-hierarchy-help-explanation/7774597#7774597  .  I would suggest altering the answer a little to make this clear.

Answer (score 57):

Annotation Approach

```
@ComponentScan({ "x.y.z", "x.y.z.dao" })
```

Comment: Do we compulsorily need to add specific packages or it can scan sub packages automatically if we only define the top level package?

Comment: @NikhilSahu nope, it's a recursive scan ( Spring 3 > )

Comment: SO link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794587/how-to-scan-multiple-paths-using-the-componentscan-annotation/21333294

Answer (score 46):

You can add multiple base packages (see [axtavt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269450/multiple-packages-in-contextcomponent-scan-spring-config/5271220#5271220)), but you can also [filter what's scanned](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters) inside the base package:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z">
   <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="(service|controller)\..*"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: @shams no need to sir me, but if the answer is correct you should mark it as accepted (click the checkmark)

Comment: Why can't you add multiple base packages? Like for instance "org.example, com.example"?

Comment: @Shervin you can. exactly as you wrote. ["Alternatively, you can specify a comma-separated list that includes the parent package of each class."](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-autodetection) (also see the expected answer)

Answer (score 20):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z"/>
```

will work since the rest of the packages are sub packages of "x.y.z". Thus, you dont need to mention each package individually.

Comment: Ok! Maybe it was another reason, but this just didn't work for me with spring mvc for portlets...

Comment: @elcadro must've been through other reasons, since this is well documented and advertised feature

Comment: Well, I can't say the opposite as many people are correcting me. I wish I could find why this didn't work for me... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Does it holds true even for the annotation based configuration?

Answer (score 6):

Another general Annotation approach:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"x.y.z"})
```

Answer (score 5):

A delayed response but to give multiple packages using **annotation** based approach we can use as below:

`@ComponentScan({"com.my.package.one","com.my.package.subpackage.two","com.your.package.supersubpackage.two"})`

Answer (score 2):

If x.y.z is the common package then you can use:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.*">
```

it will include all the package that is start with x.y.z like:
x.y.z.controller,x.y.z.service etc.

Answer (score 1):

For Example you have the package "com.abc" and you have multiple packages inside it, You can use like

```
@ComponentScan("com.abc")
```