# Spring-jersey how to expose services under more than one context

Tags: spring, rest, jersey

I use spring-jersey to expose rest services. My web.xml looks as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Let say standard. 
I have a lot of rest services in many packages and I need to goup them in two context, let say "base" and "advanced" services. Moreover I need to get rid of the "rest" prefix in url-pattern.  So I thought about group them into two packages and then in web.xml define two jersey servlets with com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages init param:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.app.rest.base</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/base/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Another Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.app.rest.advanced</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Another Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/advanced/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Unfortunately due to component scan set in applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.app" />
```

property com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages is ignored (all rest services can be accessed under each context) and it cannot be handle like that.

I am wondering how can I deal with that in other way. The only thing which I don't want to do is to set

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

that catch everyting.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple packages. Just separate them by a comma.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.app,com.sun.jersey" />
```

You can also define two component-scan items and they should work just as well, too.

If the package differentiation won't help, use a [filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters).

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
      <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*Repository"/>
   </context:component-scan>
```

And then, just make a separate applicationContext for each service but use an init-param of contextConfigLocation and init-value of the location/name of that app context. So, if you make a specific app context to load for each service, the component scan filtering will load everything you need for one service and exclude the other one.

```
<init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>WEB-INF/rest-service1.xml</param-value>
</init-paraam>
```

Actually, if you make a separate xml file for each, you can just go back to using the different package at that point, I believe.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269450/multiple-packages-in-contextcomponent-scan-spring-config

Comment: The problem is that base-package is set in that way that all rest services are available under both contexts.

Comment: You can try a filter. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters

Comment: I added some more that might help.

Comment: It should work. I am just wondering if there is any other option to deal with it without "package" approach.