# How to scan multiple paths using the @ComponentScan annotation?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm using Spring 3.1 and bootstrapping an application using the `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan` attributes.

The actual start is done with

```
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyRootConfigurationClass.class);
```

This Configuration class is annotated with

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.my.package")
public class MyRootConfigurationClass
```

and this works fine. However I'd like to be more specific about the packages I scan so I tried.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.my.package.first,com.my.package.second")
public class MyRootConfigurationClass
```

However this fails with errors telling me it can't find components specified using the `@Component` annotation.

What is the correct way to do what I'm after?

Thanks

Comment: Two correct answers given at about the same time as far as I can tell. I'll give the accept to hage just because he has less points, but thank you both.

Comment: If you are wondering the same thing for **kotlin** version check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/62818187/7747942

Answer (score 187, accepted):

[@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) uses string array, like this:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.my.package.first","com.my.package.second"})
```

When you provide multiple package names in only one string, Spring interprets this as one package name, and thus can't find it.

Answer (score 53):

There is another **type-safe** *alternative* to specifying a base-package location as a String. [See the API here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#basePackageClasses%28%29), but I've also illustrated below:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {ExampleController.class, ExampleModel.class, ExmapleView.class})
```

Using the **basePackageClasses** specifier with your class references will tell Spring to scan those packages (just like the mentioned *alternatives*), but this method is both **type-safe** and adds **IDE support** for future refactoring -- a huge plus in my book.

Reading from the API, Spring suggests creating a no-op marker class or interface in each package you wish to scan that serves no other purpose than to be used as a reference for/by this attribute.

IMO, I don't like the marker-classes *(but then again, they are pretty much just like the package-info classes)* but the type safety, IDE support, and drastically reducing the number of base packages needed to include for this scan is, with out a doubt, a far better option.

Comment: Could someone explain why @ComponentScan({"com.app", "com.controllers"}) doesn't work for me but @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses ={"com.controllers"}) does work nice ? I find it boring writing every class name

Comment: You only have to specify one class in the package, for the package you want to scan. This is known as a marker class. If you need to scan a package higher in the hierarchy that has no classes, spring suggests a technique using a  "spring marker" interface or final class defined in that package solely for the purpose of package scanning.

Comment: Thank you.  I am so sick of tracking down #wheresWaldo with string-magic/magic-strings.

Answer (score 21):

Provide your package name separately, it requires a [`String[]`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#basePackages()) for package names.

Instead of this:

```
@ComponentScan("com.my.package.first,com.my.package.second")
```

Use this:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.my.package.first","com.my.package.second"})
```

Comment: Java's "when is a comma-separated", "when is it a string-array", "when is it a string varargs" jigsaw puzzle drives me nuts sometimes.

Answer (score 14):

Another way of doing this is using the `basePackages` field; which is a field inside ComponentScan annotation.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.firstpackage","com.secondpackage"})
```

If you look into the ComponentScan annotation .class from the jar file you will see a basePackages field that takes in an array of Strings

```
public @interface ComponentScan {
String[] basePackages() default {};
}
```

Or you can mention the classes explicitly. Which takes in array of classes

```
Class<?>[]  basePackageClasses
```

Answer (score 5):

You use ComponentScan to scan multiple packages using

`@ComponentScan({"com.my.package.first","com.my.package.second"})`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use @ComponentScans annotation:

```
@ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("com.my.package.first"),
                          @ComponentScan("com.my.package.second") })
```

Comment: Please consider adding explanation to your answer

Answer (score 2):

I use:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.package1","com.package2","com.package3", "com.packagen"})
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have added this dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks after spending close to half an hour this was the missing dependency

Comment: Spring Context is the only required dependency for those annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"package1", "package2"})
```

define it at top before class.

*Edit: the brackets must be around all the base packages, not a pair of brackets per package*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).