# Using multiple path in @ComponentScan is not working

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm having a problem using multiple path in component scan. I tried the solution from here [How to scan multiple paths using the @ComponentScan annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794587/how-to-scan-multiple-paths-using-the-componentscan-annotation) but it gives me error:

[image: example]

```
@ComponentScan({"com.tx.loader", "com.tx.common"})
@SpringBootApplication
```

It says

```sh
Unexpected tokens (Use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
```

I'm using Kotlin and Intellij IDE.

Comment: Did you try `@ComponentScan(arrayOf("com.tx.loader","com.tx.common"))` ?

Comment: Type mismatch, Required is String but found Array<String>

Comment: Did you try `@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.tx.loader","com.tx.common"})`?

Comment: Yes I already tried that and it also gives me the same error `Unexpected tokens (Use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)`

Comment: You can check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794587/how-to-scan-multiple-paths-using-the-componentscan-annotation

Comment: I already checked that, it is indicated on my post

Comment: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["org.my.package", "org.my.package2"])` should work (I tested it on a configuration class)

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you don't use `{}` for array declaration, should use `[]` instead. In your particular case you can also use simplified notation

```
@ComponentScan("com.tx.loader", "com.tx.common")
```

or traditional ('basePackages' or 'value' seems to work equally in the annotation):

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.tx.loader", "com.tx.common"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey in **Kotlin** I found `@ComponentScan` to be a bit tricky.
Here is how I used it, hopefully it matches your case:

To specify the base package classes:

```kotlin
@ComponentScan(
basePackageClasses = [com.tx.loader.Example1::class, com.tx.common.Example2::class])
)
```

Or use this one to specify the package names:

```kotlin
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = ["com.tx.loader", "com.tx.common"]
)
```

Or you could use it in test with the Filter for services or components to autowire only what you need:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@ComponentScan(
    includeFilters = [ComponentScan.Filter(Service::class), ComponentScan.Filter(Component::class)],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one solved my problem 
Place it above the `main` function

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.*"])
fun main(...) {...}
```