# Putting packages in <context:component-scan base-package=""/>

Tags: spring

I have multiple packages under src/ folder, e.g. `com.banking.controller`, `com.banking.dao`, `com.banking.service`. How do I provide them in

```
<context:component-scan base-package=""/>
```

Do I have to add packages separately each time giving context component scan with the respective package name?

Comment: comma delimit the package names - package1, package2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple packages in context:component-scan, spring config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269450/multiple-packages-in-contextcomponent-scan-spring-config)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just comma delimit the package names:

```
<context component-scan base-package="package1, package2"/>
```