# Possible to use the "type" as an annotation parameter in Scala?

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm trying to tell the ComponentScan annotation in Spring to import just a single class following this example: [using ComponentScan or context:component-scan with only one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022117/using-componentscan-or-contextcomponent-scan-with-only-one-class)

```
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {"com.example.controllers"}, 
    useDefaultFilters = false,
    includeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ExampleController.class)
    })
class MyControllerTestConfig {  
}
```

I believe this is ported to Scala as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = Array("com.example.controllers"), 
    useDefaultFilters = false,
    includeFilters = Array(
        new ComponentScan.Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,   // fails
            value = Array(classOf[ExampleController]))
    ))
class MyControllerTestConfig {  
}
```

However, Scala doesn't let me use the word "type" as a parameter as it is a keyword in scala :-(

Is there a way to supply "type" as an annotation parameter in scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using backticks you can use `type` as a keyword.

e.g.

```
val `type` :String = "abc"
```