# ComponentScan.basePackageClasses vs ComponentScan.basePackages to register a single Spring webMVC Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to add a single specific controller class to my Spring WebApplicationContext. I ran across the following example: (its in Scala, but is adapted from here: [using ComponentScan or context:component-scan with only one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022117/using-componentscan-or-contextcomponent-scan-with-only-one-class))

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan(
  basePackages = Array("com.example.controllers"),
  useDefaultFilters = false,
  includeFilters = Array(
    new ComponentScan.Filter(`type` = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
      value = Array(classOf[com.example.controllers.MyController]))))
class MyConfig {
}
```

This works nicely (but is very verbose).
But Spring's @ComponentScan also has basePackageClasses

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan( basePackageClasses=Array(classOf[com.example.controllers.MyController])) 
class MyConfig {
}
```

Of basePackageClasses, Spring's docs says:

```
Type-safe alternative to basePackages() for specifying the packages to
scan for annotated components.
```

However, while the first ComponentScan correctly adds only com.example.controllers.MyController, but the second cause all of my @Controller to be scanned and added! Why? What's the use of basePackageClasses?

Example like: https://github.com/mikaelhg/springmvc-example/blob/master/src/main/java/mikaelhg/example/ExampleConfiguration.java
suggest that basePackageClasses can be used to load a single component.

---

Update:

As an aside, replacing:

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan(
  basePackages = Array("com.example.controllers"),
  useDefaultFilters = false,
  includeFilters = Array(
    new ComponentScan.Filter(`type` = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
      value = Array(classOf[com.example.controllers.MyController]))))
class MyConfig {
}
```

with

```
@Configuration 
class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  var myController = new com.example.controllers.MyController

}
```

it seems that MyController never gets gets connected to the servlet (the behavior changed to 404-NotFound) -- when added to a WebApplicationContext.

Comment: If you only want that specific class, just specify it as a bean instead of trying to scan it.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried -- I've updated my example with what I tried. This may add the bean to the spring context, but apparently, its not registered as a controller in WebApplicationContext, so the behavior's not strictly the same. Anyone know why?

Comment: @user48956 You're missing `@EnableWebMvc`.

Comment: If I add @EnableWebMvc and add MyController as a bean, then MyController is created but not connected as a controller that accessible through web requests (HTTP-404) :-(

Comment: I'm smelling multiple contexts.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The full javadoc for that attribute reads

> Type-safe alternative to basePackages() for specifying the packages to
>   scan for annotated components. **The package of each class specified
>   will be scanned.**
>
> Consider creating a special no-op marker class or interface in each
>   package that serves no purpose other than being referenced by this
>   attribute.

By type-safe, you can't make any mistakes with the `String` value of the name of the package. If you specify an incorrect class, it will fail at compile time.

When you specify `basePackageClasses`, Spring will scan the package (and *subpackages*) of the classes you specify. This is a nice trick with no-op classes/interfaces like `Controllers`, `Services`, etc. Put all your controllers in one package containing the `Controllers` class and specify your `Controllers` class in the `basePackageClasses`. Spring will pick them all up.

You still need to specify the filters.