# How to configure component-scan by annotation only in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I'm running a war file on a tomcat webserver environment.

I have an annotation based config for `@Beans`, and a xml config for webservices:

```
@Configuration
//@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ...)
public class AppConfig {
    //beans @Bean
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="..."/>
    <jaxws:endpoint ... />
</bean>
```

Problem: I would like to define `@ComponentScan` by annotation only to have typesafety. But if I do so, the scanning is not performed. In contrast, when I use `<context:component-scan..` everything works fine.

Is `Spring` component scanning within a webserver tied to configuration with xml for the package scanning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130166/componentscan-basepackageclasses-vs-componentscan-basepackages-to-register-a-sin

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go through http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06s02.html
Something Like.

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("com.company") // search the com.company package for @Component classes
    @ImportXml("classpath:com/company/data-access-config.xml")        
    public class Config {
    }
```

Comment: As written above this is exactly what I have and which does not work in combination with additional applicationContext.xml on a tomcat.

Comment: than i think you need to import the xml. I have added it after @ComponentScan

Comment: This is now @ImportResource instead of ImportXml