# How to define @ComponentScan without XML and Annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-annotations

How to Define ComponentScan Without Using annotation or Using XML in Spring? Is there any way to set componentScan using java code?

Comment: suppose you refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883987/how-to-configure-component-scan-by-annotation-only-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

[This blog says:](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/how-to-use-springs-webapplicationinitializer/)

> With the WebApplicationInitializer, Spring Framework Web MVC
>   applications can now rid themselves of web.xml.  Additional
>   configuration/implementations are available for programmatically
>   registering the DispatcherServlet and configuring the Spring container

You should be using something like this:

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
       AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

       ctx.scan("com.package.name");
       //the rest of initialization
    }
 }
```