# ComponentScan code smell? When running unit tests, I get Error creating bean, no qualifying bean of type, even though bean exists in Spring beans list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

i have a config class in a config package that looks like this:

```
package com.x.y.appName.config

@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { Application.class })
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
```

my project is failing on build within SomeClass that uses the AppConfig bean, saying:

```
Error creating bean with name 'someClass': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'appConfig'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type
```

**But when I stdout print the list of beans Spring is aware of, it lists appConfig there**

SomeClass is also in the config package, and looks like this:

```
package com.x.y.appName.config;

@Configuration
public class SomeClass implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
AppConfig appConfig;
```

but if i add this to SomeClass, it builds fine and all tests pass:

```
@ComponentScan("com.x.y.appName.config")
```

in the past ive never needed to ComponentScan the same package that another bean is also declared in

again to clarify, i can bootRun the app just fine, but this spring error is throwing during build or test. do i need to add something to the unit tests? **I dont have unit tests for either of the above classes as they would be too frivolous.** So what could be going on? Do I need to annotate other unit tests somewhere?

Comment: something related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130166/componentscan-basepackageclasses-vs-componentscan-basepackages-to-register-a-sin

Comment: @Deadpool not really...?

Comment: Is the Application class annotated with @Component ?

Comment: @AnishB.  no its annotated with "@SpringBootApplication" ... i thought this achieved what "@Component" does and then some

Comment: @AnishB.  ive written many spring apps and never once annotated the main class with "@Component" ... anyway, this did not solve or change anything, i still need to component scan in the same package for build to pass, which really makes no sense to me