# How can I specify into the Spring XML configuration to perform the component-scan on two different packages?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, package, component-scan

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have the following problem.

In the application on which I am working I have 2 controllers classes declared into two different packages.

So I am trying to specify into my XML configuration the second package that have to be scanned by the **component scan** setting.

So if I only have this setting works fine (but I scan only a package):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="it.mycompmany.myproject.registrazione"></context:component-scan>
```

But if I try to specify that have to be scanned two different package, in this way:

```
<!-- Controller -->
<context:component-scan base-package="it.mycompmany.myproject.registrazione">
</context:component-scan>

<context:component-scan base-package="it.mycompmany.myproject.login>
</context:component-scan>
```

Eclipse give me error on the second **component-scan** setting tag:

```
The value of attribute "base-package" associated with an element type "context:component-scan" must not contain the '<' character.
```

What is the problem? How can I correctly specify that I have to scan two different packages? What am I missing?

Comment: The `base-package` attribute takes a comma separated list of values. Just use `base-package="it.mycompmany.myproject.registrazione,it.mycompmany.myproject.login"`. Your code fails btw because the second one misses a `"` on the end.

Comment: Is the closing comma in one of the `context:component-scan` missing in your real code too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple packages in context:component-scan, spring config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269450/multiple-packages-in-contextcomponent-scan-spring-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify multiple packages using comma

```
<context:component-scan base-package="it.mycompmany.myproject.registrazione,it.mycompmany.myproject.login">
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: Surely it needs the closing comma?

Answer (score -2):

Change from

```
<!-- Controller -->
<context:component-scan base-package="it.istruzione.iam.ssum.registrazione">
</context:component-scan>

<context:component-scan base-package="it.istruzione.iam.ssum.login>
</context:component-scan>
```

to

```
<!-- Controller -->
<context:component-scan base-package="it.istruzione.iam.ssum.registrazione">
</context:component-scan>

<context:component-scan base-package="it.istruzione.iam.ssum.login">
</context:component-scan>
```