# Autowiring ByType gives null .but no errors in logs

Tags: spring, autowired

### Service class

```
 package com.company.service;

 @org.springframework.stereotype.Service
 public class UserWorkflow {
     private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserWorkflow.class)
     @Autowired
     public UserMessageViewDAO MessageViewDAO;
 }
```

### Dao class

```
package com.company.dao;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public class UserMessageViewDAO extends BaseDao{
    public UserMessageViewDAO () {

    }
}
```

### in applicationContexe.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.service"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

`@Autowire` annotation is not working properly. It is displaying value of `MessageViewDAO` as `null` when called methods in service class .But there is no errors in the log when application is deploying.
Could you help me to find a problem?

Comment: How do you obtain an instance of UserWorkflow?

Comment: instance of UserWorkflow is obtained by Autowiring the UserWorkflow.This is not working

Comment: I don't understand the '@Autowired public UserMessageViewDAO MessageViewDAO. Your code shows that UserMessageViewDAO is a concrete class/implementation. Is MessageViewDAO an Interface? If so, then '@Autowired MessageViewDAO UserMessageViewDAO would be correct.

Comment: Here i used only classes.no interfaces used.@Autowired public UserMessageViewDAO MessageViewDAO.Here the UserMessageViewDAO is a class.MessageViewDAO is not an interface

Answer (score 0):

The second context:component-scan overwrites the first one, which is why com.company.dao is not scanned. If you want to use several packages, include them with something like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.dao, com.company.service" />
```

or, in short (package scan is recursive):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company" />
```

You might also want to have a look at:  [multiple packages in context:component-scan, spring config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269450/multiple-packages-in-contextcomponent-scan-spring-config)

Edit 2016-09-12: Use the annotations @Service and @Repositiory. The Annotations @org..springframework.stereotype. ... look weird.

Comment: Thanks @deepblue for ur answer.I tried it but no luck.